# Availability warning despite setting iOS Deployment Target

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using PDFKit which was introduced in iOS 11.0. When I define PDFView I get the warning:

```
PDFView' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer
```

Which is fine, but to silence this warning I set the iOS Deployment Target to 11.0 (which I understand to be the minimum iOS version the app will run on). However, even after setting this deployment target the warnings remain. I also tried setting the deployment target to iOS 11.1, but the warnings are still there.

I can get rid of the warnings using clang pragmas or:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {}
```

but I don't understand why setting the minimum deployment target doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check iOS version for the project (not for target). Also try to clean up and recompile:

Holding Alt click Product -> Clean Build Folder. Then recompile.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Volkov - that pointed me in the right direction. I had set it for the project but not for the target - not sure why you would want these to be different?